# Laravel - exists() method returning false in local and true in production server

Tags: php, laravel

I just came across this weird problem. I was deploying my code to a test server and everything is the same.

I have a simple `$laptop = Laptops::where('name', 'Mac')->first() ?: new BlankLaptop();`

The `BlankLaptop` class is an empty class that extends the `Laptops` class.

And then I do

```
if ($laptop->exists()) // do something
```

The problem is that it always returns true in production, even though when I `dd($laptop)`, the result is the **same** in both the production and the local server.

**However**, when I do `$laptop->exists` (without the brackets), it does return the right value.

Is there a different between `->exists()` and `->exists`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**There's definitely a difference.**

1. `$laptop->exists` checks [the `exists` **property**](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c31a9c5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L184-L189) on the model, which determines whether the *current* model has been saved to the database.
2. `$laptop->exists()` calls [the `exists` **method**](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/c31a9c5807f001f77a25bf7595a7d8e9b84faaf4/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1935-L1953) on the query builder. It's equivalent to this:

   ```php
   $doesAnyLaptopExist = Laptop::query()->exists();
   ```

   ...which runs this SQL statement:

   ```sql
   select exists(select * from `laptops`)
   ```

   ...to determine if there are *any* records in your table.

**Huge difference.**