# Laravel update if not exists (duplicate check)

Tags: php, laravel

I don't want to have dupliactes into my *users* table. This would be ok:

```
╔═══╦════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ firstname  ║ lastname    ║ dateOfBirth ║
╠═══╬════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ John       ║ Mat         ║ 1999-12-01  ║
║ 2 ║ Dave       ║ Bittner     ║ 1950-06-02  ║
║ 3 ║ John       ║ Mat         ║ 1900-11-02  ║
╚═══╩════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

In my Laravel application (`UserController`), I am checking if the user already exists by calling the `firstOrCreate` Method (creating a new user):

```
public function store(UserRequest $request) {

   $user = User::firstOrCreate([
        'firstname'             => request('firstname'),
        'lastname'              => request('lastname'),
        'dateOfBirth'           => request('dateOfBirth'),
    ]);

    if($user->wasRecentlyCreated) {
        // new
    }else {
        // existing
    }

    return redirect('/users');
}
```

This worked pretty well. Now, I can create a similar user successful (like the entry with the `id=3` in the example table above). If I edit the birthday from entry 3 into `1999-12-01`, Laravel says it is OK, but it isn't (duplicate with `id=1`) !

I also want to check on update, if the entry already exists (duplicate check after every update). I am searching a `updateIfNotDuplicate` method or something like that (like the `firstOrCreate` for updates).

This is my `update` function in the `UserController`:

```
public function update(User $user, UserRequest $request) {
    $user->update([
        'firstname'             => request('firstname'),
        'lastname'              => request('lastname'),
        'dateOfBirth'           => request('dateOfBirth'),
    ]);

    return redirect('/users');
}
```

Comment: I think using updateOrCreate() will fix your problem

Comment: You have a `UserRequest` object, why not add a `unique` constraint to the `dateOfBirth` column?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: It is also possible that two users with the same birthday but a different name exists. I tried to create a MCVE. My real table is a much bigger. You could see it as a hole-table-composite-key (instead of the id field).

Comment: Maybe this feed can help you [https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-check-for-unique-column-combanation-from-the-validation-rule?page=2](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/how-to-check-for-unique-column-combanation-from-the-validation-rule?page=2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```php
public function update(User $user, UserRequest $request) {

    $update = [
        'firstname'             => request('firstname'),
        'lastname'              => request('lastname'),
        'dateOfBirth'           => request('dateOfBirth'),
    ];

    // find if your updated user already exists 
    $new_user = $user->firstOrNew($update);

    // Update if the no changes has been made or if no user have been founded
    if($new_user->id == $user->id OR !$new_user->exists){
        $user->update($update);

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! You need to change `!$new_user->exists()` into `!$new_user->exists` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/41082793/2056125). After this, is worked pretty well. Thanks a lot for this solution!